# How to prove rational cuts satisfy the multiplication

Tags: analysis

I'm reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and I'm trying to prove the eighth step of constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$

$r \in \mathbb{Q}, r^{*} = \left\{p\in \mathbb{Q}|p <r\right\}$, and $r^{*}$ is a Dedekind cut.
$r^{*} < s^{*} \Leftrightarrow r^{*}\subseteq s^{*}$
for two Dedekind cuts $\alpha > 0^*, \beta > 0^*$

$$
\alpha \beta = \left\{p \in \mathbb{Q}| \exists r \in \alpha, s\in \beta,r >0, s>0, p\le rs\right\}
$$

Now I what to prove $r^*s^*=(rs)^*$, suppose $r^* >0^*, s^* >0^*$
here's my prove

Proof:

$\forall p \in r^*s^*$
$\exists r^{\prime} \in r^*,s^{\prime}\in s^*, 0 <r^{\prime}<r, 0 < s^{\prime} <s, p \le r^{\prime}s^{\prime}$
$$
p \le r^{\prime}s^{\prime} < rs\Rightarrow p \in \left(rs\right)^{*}
$$
so $r^{*}s^{*}\subseteq (rs)^{*}$

and now I don't know how to prove $(rs)^{*}\subseteq r^{*}s^{*}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me demonstrate my vision, although, there,  probably, exists a more elegant solution:

Let's take $p\in(rs)^*$, where $p,r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $p<rs\Rightarrow \frac{p}{r}<s$. Let's consider such $s'\in\mathbb{Q}$, that $\frac{p}{r}<s'<s$. Obviously $r'=\frac{p}{s'}<r$. Now if we consider $p=s'\cdot\frac{p}{s'}=s'\cdot r'$, then, as $s'<s, r'<r$, we get  $p\in r^*s^*$.

Comment: thanks a lot,  now I know how to prove.

Comment: but I think there's a little mistake, we what to get $p \in r^*s^*$, as we known, $s^{\prime}\in s^*, r^{\prime} \in r^{*}$, we can get $p \le r^{\prime} s^{\prime}$, so that $p \in r^*s^*$

Comment: Yes. The last formula have been corrected, but there are no errors in the proof.

Comment: @Nightmare. By given proof is shown not inequality, as you wrote in your comment, but exact equality $p=r'\cdot s'$.

Comment: $p = r^{\prime} s^{\prime}$ implies that $p\le r^{\prime} s^{\prime}$

Comment: Of course, but not reverse. Exact factorization is more informative and directly satisfies definition in same way as in previous point for sum.